# Detect video file corruption

Tags: windows, video

I am looking for a program that can detect corrupted video files in a given folder and its subfolders. It should work on Microsoft Windows. Any price and license is fine. The more supported video file format, the better.

Comment: I haven't found any program so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.